# I want to save this generated html2canvas img in php Db. Please mention what code lines should I add

Tags: php

I have this script tag in my page and it is successfully downloading as html to canvas. I want to save this generated html2canvas in phpMyAdmin.
This is my code added-

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function downloadimage() {
        //var container = document.getElementById("image-wrap"); //specific element on page
        var container = document.getElementById("htmltoimage");; // full page 
        html2canvas(container, { allowTaint: true }).then(function (canvas) {

            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.download = "html_image.jpg";
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.click();
        });
    }


//var container = document.getElementById("image-wrap"); //specific element on page
        var container = document.body; // full page 
        html2canvas(container).then(function(canvas) {
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.download = "invoice.png";
            link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.target = '_blank';
            link.click();
        });
        var container = document.getElementById("htmltoimage");; // full page 
    html2canvas(container,{allowTaint : true}).then(function(canvas) {
    
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.download = "invoice.png";
        link.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        link.target = '_blank';
        link.click();
    });
            </script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: You're going to need to learn about PHP, MySQL and Ajax. Ajax will transfer your request from Javascript to PHP. PHP will help you insert the information in the database.